# Getting reference data from Graphql using Gatsby/Contentful

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm struggling to get the data from the reference part of my Graphql. I got a Contentful content model that includes references as you can see in the query below.

Now, I got a simple page like this, where I query data from Contentful:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: {
            id,
            title,
            featuredActivities: { id, title },
        },
    },
}) => {


    return (
                                    <article key={id}>
                                        <div>
                                            <h3>{title}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>

                                    <article key={featuredActivities.id}>
                                        <div>
                                            <h3>{featuredActivities.title}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
query GetSinglePage($slug: String) {
  islands: contentfulPage (slug: {eq: $slug}) {
        id
        title
        featuredActivities {
            id
            title
            category
            price
            image {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
              }
            }
          }
      }
  }
`
export default PageTemplate
```

And now I want to get the data for this part of the query:

```
featuredActivities {
            id
            title
            category
            price
            image {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
              }
            }
          }
```

I've tried this:

```
const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: {
            featuredActivities: { id },
            featuredActivities: { title },
        },
    },
```

and added it like this into the :

```
<article key={featuredActivities.id}>
  <h3>{featuredActivities.title}</h3>
</article>
```

But it's not working, does someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*.?what error do you receive?

Comment: The content is not displaying.

Comment: Seems like FeaturedActivities and islands will both be an array?

Comment: So how can I get the data from FeaturedActivities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now I want to get the data for this part of the query

You can't destructure all items of the array like this:

```
const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: {
            featuredActivities: { id },
            featuredActivities: { title },
        },
    },
```

Why? Because it's an array of objects and the structure (`{}`) doesn't match the type of the nested item. And, in case it was, and you will need to enter each specific position.

You may need to:

```
const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: [{
            featuredActivities: { id },
            featuredActivities: { title },
        }],
    },
```

Notice the wrapping square brackets (`[]`).

However, as I said, it's not ideal since you need to print each specific position of the array of an unknown length. The best and optimal solution is to destructure until `featuredActivities` and loop through all elements:

```
const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: {
            id,
            title,
            featuredActivities,
        },
    },
}) => {


    return <>
     {featuredActivities.map(({title, id})=>{
       return <div key={id}>{title}</div>
     })}
    </>
}
```

In that way, you can destructure inside the same loop in `({title, id})`, since you are getting for each specific position (`featuredActivity`, the iterable variable), the `title` and the `id` (and so on for the rest of the needed fields).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Islands` and `featuredActivities` are not array or objects and you are getting the correct data from GraphQL query, you just need to correct how you destructure and use the values. Also since you cannot have clashing variable names, you will have to rename the variables from `featuredActivities`

```
const PageTemplate = ({
    data: {
        islands: {
            id, title
            featuredActivities: { id: featuredId , title: featuredTitle },
        },
    },
    ...

    <article key={featuredId}>
      <h3>{featuredTitle}</h3>
    </article>
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your reply. I think I've tried that let me double check real quick

Comment: I'm getting this error when im doing it like that:  27:35  error  Parsing error: Argument name clash

Comment: Are your also destructuring id and title from islands?

Comment: Yes, I want to destructure the title from islands and also from featuredActivities

Comment: I've updated my code in the question for you to understand better what im trying to do

Comment: Im not getting an error anymore but I still can't see the title or get the id

Comment: Can you just try `const PageTemplate = ({
    data }) => {` and log data to see if you are actually receiving the data from query

Comment: Even with  `featuredActivities: { id: featuredId , title: featuredTitle }` I receive the data. But maybe `<h3>featuredTitle</h3>` must be wrong ?

Comment: Inside the featuredActivities ID are 4 other ID's and then comes the title

Comment: I've added a picture in my question from the data structure that I've received. You can see there are 4 different ID's I've receiving in the main ID